# Youtube crashes

Tags: youtube

I shut my galaxy s3 off while I had a video uploading to youtube. Now, whenever I try to go to the uploads tab, the app crashes. I tried logging out, clearing the cache and restarting my phone and nothing works. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to uninstall the latest update , this could be a bug , uninstall the latest update and reinstall again, this will fix your issue